# Show complement of language in same complexity class?

Tags: complexity-classes, formal-languages

If $L$ is a binary language ($\Sigma = (0, 1)^*$) and $\overline{L}$ is the complement of $L$, the set of binary strings not in $L$.

How can I show that, if $L$ is in the complexity class $P$, then so is $\overline{L}$?

Comment: Exact Duplicate: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/10257/2152

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deciding $L$ means you have a way to answer "YES" or "NO" on each input.

$\bar L$ is the complement language of $L$: if some input is in $L$, then it is not in $\bar L$ (and vice versa)..

Thus, deciding $L$ and deciding $\bar L$ are equivalent up to the final answer. If an algorithm to decide one of them takes $x$ time, the similar algorithm (up to the final state) for the other language will take... the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Given a polynomial time algorithm for $L$, come up with a polynomial time algorithm for $\overline{L}$.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this too. The following algorithm decides membership in $\bar L$ in polynomial time given that membership in $L$ can be decided in polytime : `if not string in L: return YES else: return NO`. Correct?

Comment: Correct. That's exactly the idea.